# Query select count return more that the real number

Tags: sql

Guys i have got a very strange issue i have a SQL statement  the count return more than the actual records of the query for example:

```
select EmployeName, DepartmentName from company;
```

return 200 records
if I add

```
select count(*) from (select EmployeName, DepartmentName from company)`;
```

return 201

and note that is a very complicated query contains 2 union
any suggestions about the reason behind this?
thanks

Comment: you better add some sample data to your question

Comment: Does your SQL client limit the number of rows somehow?

Comment: What do you get if you run just `select count(*) from company`